# Linear regression model: Why are the predicted values always wrong?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to do a simple linear regression model, my dataset are numbers from 1 to 10. I'm trying to train the model to predict that for any given output, for example 3, the output should be the value of the input (`y = x`).

The predictions are always wrong. Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

```js
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");

const xArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const yArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const createModel = () => {
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1], units: 1, useBias: true })); //input layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true })); //output layer
  return model;
};

const convertToTensor = () => {
  return tf.tidy(() => {
    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(xArray, [xArray.length, 1]);
    const outputTensor = tf.tensor2d(yArray, [yArray.length, 1]);

    return {
      inputs: inputTensor,
      outputs: outputTensor,
    };
  });
};

async function trainModel(model, inputs, trueValues) {
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
    metrics: ["mse"]
  });

  return await model.fit(inputs, trueValues, {
    batchSize: 2,
    epochs: 5,
    learningRate: 0.04
  });
}

function testModel(model, testValue) {
  return tf.tidy(() => model.predict(tf.tensor2d([testValue], [1, 1]));
}

const run = async testValue => {
  const model = createModel();
  const tensorData = convertToTensor();
  await trainModel(model, tensorData.inputs, tensorData.outputs);
  const prediction = testModel(model, testValue);
  console.log(prediction.toString());
};

run(5);
```

Comment: How was this closed as duplicate? The linked question is about a classification problem of images. This one is a regression problem. The only thing they have in common is that both models make wrong predictions. Even the solutions are completely different (wrong classification function vs. not using the API correct and not enough epochs for training).

Comment: Even if one is a regression problem and the second a classification one, the answer is still the same - tuning the model which was highlighted in the answer for which this one is a duplicate of. I answered the question just by giving the previous link and later realized that I should flagged it instead

Comment: @edkeveked No, the answers are not the same, just look at them! This question/answer is about using the API incorrectly (**this has nothing to do with tuning!**) and not training for enough epochs. The other answer is about class prediction, confusion matrix and a wrong activation function, which all has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- You are not setting the `learningRate` value correctly. You need to pass it to the [`tf.train.adam()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#train.adam) function as first argument
- You are only learning for `5` epochs, which won't be enough in your case.

### Try it yourself

I removed the unnecessary code from your code below. You can change the `epochs` and `learning rate` values to see how it affects the resulting prediction of `5`. I changed the default value of the epoch to `50`. The predictions end up being very close to `5`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const learningRate = document.querySelector('#learning_rate').value;
  const epochs = document.querySelector('#epochs').value;

  const xArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  const yArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

  const createModel = () => {
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1], units: 1, useBias: true }));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true }));
    return model;
  };

  const convertToTensor = () => {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
      const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(xArray, [xArray.length, 1]);
      const outputTensor = tf.tensor2d(yArray, [yArray.length, 1]);
      return {
        inputs: inputTensor,
        outputs: outputTensor,
      };
    });
  };

  async function trainModel(model, inputs, trueValues) {
    model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.adam(learningRate),
      loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
      metrics: ["mse"]
    });

    const batchSize = 2;

    return await model.fit(inputs, trueValues, {
      batchSize,
      epochs,
    });
  }

  function testModel(model, testValue) {
    return tf.tidy(() => model.predict(tf.tensor2d([testValue], [1, 1])));
  }

  const run = async testValue => {
    const model = createModel();
    const tensorData = convertToTensor();
    await trainModel(model, tensorData.inputs, tensorData.outputs);
    const prediction = testModel(model, testValue);
    console.log(`Predction for 5: ${prediction.toString()}`);
  };

  run(5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

epochs: <input type="number" id="epochs" value="50" />
learning rate: <input type="number" id="learning_rate" value="0.04" />
<button id="train">Train</button>
```